# Input, left arrow key - Rust

Tags: rust, input, stdin

I wrote this code for create an user input.

```
std::io::stdout().flush().expect("Failed to flush stdout");
std::io::stdin().read_line(stdin_buffer).expect("Failed to read from stdin");
```

But when I press the left arrow key:

```
#> als -ls^[[D^[[D
```

How do you go backwards in the text?

Comment: Without an external module, you don't.  You can use backspace, of course, but if you want command-line editing, that requires a readline library.

Answer (score 2):

As mention in comment of the question, best option is to use third-party crate for this purpose. [`rustyline`](https://crates.io/crates/rustyline) may be good option.

Add this crate to your application with.

`cargo add rustyline`

Below is sample code uisng `rustyline`.

```
use rustyline::error::ReadlineError;

fn main() -> rustyline::Result<()> {
    let mut rl = rustyline::DefaultEditor::new()?;
    loop {
        let readline = rl.readline(">> ");
        match readline {
            Ok(line) => {
                let _ = rl.add_history_entry(line.as_str());
                println!("Line: {}", line);
            },
            Err(ReadlineError::Interrupted) => {
                println!("CTRL-C");
                break
            },
            Err(ReadlineError::Eof) => {
                println!("CTRL-D");
                break
            },
            Err(err) => {
                println!("err: {:?}", err);
                break
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

**TL;DR**

To implement what you are looking is possible but quite difficult(but doable) and to make that cross platform will be more challenging.

*Thing you need to do*

You need to read stdin character by character. May be in some OS/terminal you need to add extra code(As it can be buffered).Based on `ascii` value of character you need to process it.